# Is it possible to make Grafana login by default to a specific organization and not to the anonymous one?

Tags: authentication, grafana, anonymous

I’m using Grafana 8.5.10 on Windows.
I have two configured organizations:

- orgId=1 with built in authentication and some configred
  users with different access policies.
- orgId=2 configured with anonymous access that we need to
  embed some panel in a summary web page.

But when I access Grafana directly from a web browser (ip_address:3000) it defaults do the orgId=2 organization which is not meant to be normally accessed by users. I'd like it to access to the login page of orgId=1.

Is there some way to default the base access to Grafana to a specific organization (orgId=1)?

Or, as an alternative approach, is it possible to remove anonymous login and embed in the panel direct link in the summary web page some authentication token / information?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit: you what to save your users a click to button "Login", or do you what completely restrict their access to org2?

Comment: To save users login button and change org command: when I open Grafana it opens the anon org2, then after login it logs on the org2, then I have to change org2 to the non anon org1. To restrict the access to org2 would be even better but it is not necessary.

Comment: Have you tried setting default dashboard: Configuration -> Preferences -> Home dashboard?

Comment: Home Dashboard option specifies the home dashboard within an organization, it does not define the default organization.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `auto_assign_org_id: 1` in your grafana config to assign org 1 when users are created and set their default org.

Ref : https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#auto_assign_org_id